# What fraction is shaded?

Tags: mathematics, geometry

The dots around the semicircle are equally spaced. What fraction is shaded?

[image: Five dots are spaced around the semicircle, with an additional two positioned at the corners. The right corner is connected to the two on the left, while the upper right dot is connected to the top and the upper left dot. Three alternative sections are colored in.]

This puzzle is by the amazing Catriona Agg.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This becomes very easy once we add an auxiliary

> regular hexagon with its diagonals.

We will show that the largest of the three shaded regions (blue in figure a) is exactly

> [image]

> one third

of the total area

This is obvious because the triangles in b and c have the same area.

Because they have

- the same base and height

or some may prefer because

- they are made from the same two halves

or others still may skip c completely

- because the area of the triangle in b is clearly one sixth of the hexagon.

Easy.

Next we'll show that the blue shaded area and the non-shaded area are

> the same

and we'll be done.

First, we move the tiny shaded bit (Figure d) and then we are left with a matching curved bit (Figure e) and again two triangles that share their base and have the same height, half the radius (Figure f).

To summarise

> The blue, teal and non shaded regions split the total area evenly. In particular, 2/3 are shaded.

Comment: Hmm i don't follow, can't find the two triangles in the last step. The ones which share base.

Comment: @Adam Sorry I forgot to write that is in panel f. The blue solid and red outline. The base is where they touch. One triangle extends half a radius upwards the other half a radius downwards.

Answer (score 32):

The shaded fraction is

> 2/3

Step by step explanation:

> [image: 1]
>  [image: 2]
>  [image: 3]
>  [image: 4]
>  [image: 5]

Comment: damn, I was just drawing :( good job :)

Answer (score 8):

My answer is

> **Two-thirds** of the semi-circle is shaded
>
>  The area of a sector is (area of the segment) - (area of triangle subtended)
>  Suppose the angle subtended is $\theta$, the segment area
>  $= (\pi r^2 \times \frac{\theta}{360}) - (r \sin \frac{\theta}{2} \times r \cos \frac{\theta}{2}) $
>  $= r^2 (\frac{\theta \pi}{360} - \frac{\sin \theta}{2})$
>
>  Each dot is spaced at 30°, so
>
>  Area of a 30° segment
>  **A1** = $ r^2 ( \frac{30 \pi}{360} - \frac{\sin 30}{2})$
>
>  Area of a 60° segment
>  **A2** = $ r^2 ( \frac{60 \pi}{360} - \frac{\sin 60}{2})$
>
>  Area of a 120° segment
>  **A4** = $ r^2 ( \frac{120 \pi}{360} - \frac{\sin 120}{2})$
>
>  Area of a 150° segment
>  **A5** = $ r^2 ( \frac{150 \pi}{360} - \frac{\sin 150}{2})$
>
>  Area of a 180° segment
>  **A6** = $ r^2 ( \frac{180 \pi}{360} - \frac{\sin 180}{2})$
>
>  We want the area
>  **A1 + (A4 - A2) + (A6 - A5)**
>
>  Which is
>  $r^2( \frac{(30 + 120 - 60 + 180 - 150) \pi}{360} - \frac{(\sin 30 + \sin 120 - \sin 60 + \sin 180 - \sin 150)}{2})$
>
>  reducing to
>
>  $r^2( \frac{120 \pi}{360} - \frac{\sin 180}{2})$
>
>  and
>
>  $\frac{\pi r^2}{3}$
>
>  which is one third of a full circle.

Comment: I originally had an arithmetic error, now corrected.

Answer (score 6):

Had to edit because I hadn't seen the tiny bit at the top at first:

> 2/3 
>  [image]

Comment: Gotta clean this up.